# SQL Query with times in strings

Tags: sql

I have these tables in my database:

### Restaurant

- `restid` (ex. 0)
- `name` (ex. Lokotas)

### Hours

- `hourid` (ex. 0)
- `restid` (ex. 0)
- `day` (ex. mon)
- `time` (ex. 7:00 PM - 12:00 AM)

I don't know how to check in the actual day and hour if the restaurant is opened or closed. Alsso the bigger problem i have is that sometimes a restaurant open at 7 PM and close at 1 AM the next day.

PD: I know that the table Hours on column time is not the best way to save times, but i didn't this, i'm fixing other people problems.

Comment: You should probably modify your Hours table to have an OpenTime and CloseTime column, instead of one column with text.

Comment: What is your SQL *flavor*?  Time/Date functions can be implemented differently in various RDBMS.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Johnie Karr, thanks but i can't change schema i'm solving a problem, the column is a string, i'm using mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ridiculously convoluted solution (for T-SQL, not sure if that's what you're using):

```
DECLARE @openhours NVARCHAR(30)
SET @openhours = '7:00 PM - 12:30 AM'

SELECT

    CONVERT(TIME, REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(CAST((SELECT CAST((
        SELECT SUBSTRING(left(@openhours,9), Number, 1)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(left(@openhours,9)) AND
            SUBSTRING(left(@openhours,9), Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path(''))
    AS xml)) as VARCHAR(MAX))), 3, 0 , ':'))
    + CASE WHEN left(@openhours,9) LIKE '%PM%' THEN ' PM' ELSE ' AM' END) [Opens at],

    CONVERT(TIME, REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(CAST((SELECT CAST((
        SELECT SUBSTRING(right(@openhours,9), Number, 1)
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE Type='p' AND Number <= LEN(right(@openhours,9)) AND
            SUBSTRING(right(@openhours,9), Number, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' FOR XML Path(''))
    AS xml)) as VARCHAR(MAX))), 3, 0 , ':'))
    + CASE WHEN right(@openhours,9) LIKE '%PM%' THEN ' PM' ELSE ' AM' END) [Closes at]
```

Note, you don't have to declare and set the variable. You can omit those two lines and replace everywhere that I have used @openhours with whatever column name contains your open hours string.

If you don't want the value returned as a `TIME` and would prefer `VARCHAR`, just delete the outside `CONVERT(TIME, ... ... ... )` function. However, the advantage of converting to `TIME` is that now you can use DB functions to perform calculations on the results (E.g. B - A, to see how long the store stays open for, etc).

I borrowed heavily from Chris Hynes blog post [Strip non-numeric characters from a string in SQL Server](http://programcsharp.com/blog/post/strip-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-in-sql-server) and worked from there to convert the output to a DB readable `TIME`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh well, I had fun figuring it out for T-SQL anyway, taught myself a thing or two in the process. Perhaps this will be useful for someone else using my favorite RDBMS. That said, most of the functions are very similar in MySQL, so you might be able to adapt this to suit your needs. I'm not sure if you'll have `master..spt_values`, I would guess not, and the syntax for CONVERT is slightly different, but CAST, REVERSE, SUBSTRING, etc., should all behave the same way. Good luck!